# Paginated WKInterfaceTable

Tags: ios, watchkit

I'm experimenting with Apple's new WatchKit SDK, and I've run into a bit of missing functionality. I want to create a vertically scrolling, paginated list of full screen tiles of dynamic data for the user to swipe through. The WKInterfaceTable seems to be the only way to display dynamic content, but it doesn't support much customization, especially not pagination. How can I display this paginated user interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this with watchOS2 (you can now with watchOS3) – vertical paging simply isn't supported yet. For that I'd suggest filing an enhancement [radar](http://bugreport.apple.com) with Apple's bug reporting system.

As for your assessment of using a `WKInterfaceTable` to generate dynamically scrolling content, I'd say it's spot on. If you have different kinds of data that you need to display, you can certainly use different types of RowController objects to do this. The only thing you really can't do at the moment is vertical paging.

Answer (score 0):

Since watchOS3, `WKInterfaceTable` has vertical detail page pagination, provided you are using segues with your `RowControllers`. Using this feature, you should be able to realize the interface you want. See [Supporting Item Pagination](https://developer.apple.com/reference/watchkit/wkinterfacetable).